# Wirelessly Transfer Files between Android and Windows without Losing Modified Timestamp

Tags: windows, android, file-management, file-synchronization, data-transfer

I am looking for software that allows the user to wirelessly transfer files from Android devices to Windows computers while maintaining the modified timestamp (aka datestamp or simply "date and time") of the files.

Requirements:

1. Must be able to transfer multiple files or entire folders.
2. The software can run on the Android side or the Windows side, or both.
3. Must transfer large files as fast as possible (not sure whether or not this removes bluetooth options).

Preferences:

1. Ideally, I would like to use the PC to select which files to transfer from the Android device, since it is easier to use a bigger screen and keyboard.
2. Prefer something that can work with WiFi Direct so that no WiFi network is required.
3. Prefer that in addition to transferring from Android to Windows, to also transfer files in the other direction.
4. Strongly prefer a solution that allows the user to view the Android files on the Windows computer just like they were a local (or networked) drive.  The idea here is easy drag and drop in both directions.  Strongly prefer that it will work with FreeCommander XE on the Windows side (which currently does not support FTP).

Why:
When the Modify timestamp is changed during a transfer, it makes it hard to tell which version is newer or if the file has been changed.  Also, for photographs, it makes it harder to quickly determine when the photo was taken (you have to rely on the EXIF info, or use a separate program to change back all the Modify timestamps to conform to the EXIF info).

What I've Tried:

1. Superbeam - Fail. Changes the Modified timestamps.
2. ShareIt - Fail. Changes the Modified timestamps.
3. AirDroid - Fail. Changes the Modified timestamps.
4. ES File Explorer - Fail. Cannot prevent it from making undisclosed calls to IP addresses in China (seriously, check it out for yourself).

(If interested, also see [this similar question I posted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/wirelessly-transfer-files-between-two-android-devices-without-losing-modified-ti) to achieve this between two Android devices when no WiFi is available.)

Comment: Maintaining a timestamp has been an issue for a while now. See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25460 - this may be the reason why you don't see any apps that maintain timestamps. Relying on EXIF data may not be ideal as that's relative to the configuration of the device/camera.

Comment: The only apps I know taking care for timestamps are synchronisation apps (e.g. FolderSync). Unfortunately, those won't fit your "one-time-pick" idea (to decide anew on each xfer what files to take): you'd have to configure the xfer directory pair(s) in advance.

Comment: @HalfCrazed That is an amazingly relevant thread.  Thank you.  Comment #17 in that thread states: "So, the Android team will ignore this bug FOREVER just like the others 5k+ bugs ignored in this website???".  It's unfortunate how the Android team doesn't get involved when people take their time to clearly describe Android bugs to them.

Comment: It is unfortunate, indeed... which is why Android is still buggy to this day (in my opinion). I have the new Lollipop on my Galaxy S5 and it's terribly slow, even after resetting. It's downright ridiculous that the Android OS is such a resource hog and terrible garbage management/optimizations. Android is down the path of self destruction IMO.

Comment: @HalfCrazed I agree.  They seem to simply ignore bug reports for years without providing feedback to their customer-base.  Android reminds me of Windows 3.1, but instead of Lollipop being like Windows XP, it seems to behave more like Windows 3.0.  Not providing a simple way to move files off of an Android device without losing the timestamp is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Bit hacky, but if you're rooted, install SambaDroid - which gives your Android the ability to host a network shared SMB folder. You could then use ROBOCOPY from the Windows machine to copy from/to the share on the Android device. ROBOCOPY can preserve timestamps:

[ROBOCOPY - how to preserve timestamps](https://serverfault.com/questions/288631/what-switches-can-robocopy-use-to-preserve-file-and-directory-times-on-the-targe)

[SambaDroid - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sambadroid)