# Wirelessly Transfer Files between Two Android Devices without Losing Modified Timestamp

Tags: android, file-management, file-synchronization, offline, data-transfer

I just posted [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18049/wirelessly-transfer-files-between-android-and-windows-without-losing-modified-ti) regarding wirelessly transferring files between Android and Windows without losing the Modified timestamps of each file.

This is a "sister" question.  What software will allow the user to wirelessly transfer files between two Android devices without losing the Modified timestamps AND does not need any WiFi network to function?

I'm thinking a WiFi direct solution would be ideal, but am interested in any solutions.

Requirements:

1. Must be fast (3Mbps minimum).
2. Must be able to select multiple files or entire folders.
3. Works when no WiFi or other network available.

What I've Tried:

1. Superbeam - Fail. Changes the Modified timestamps.
2. ShareIt - Fail. Changes the Modified timestamps.